# How to SUM a range preevaluated by a formula

Tags: excel-formula

Lets say we have two cells A1 and A2:

```
A1: A, B, 13
A2: C,B,14
```

Which are Strings. I want to add the values at the end of each cell-string.
Hence what I do to extract a value of a specific cell:

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(A1, SEARCH(",",A1))))
```

Returns 13 as a VALUE (or int).

Now, is there a way to add A1 and A2 in a SUM function? I could not find a way to loop through each A cell in a SUM range and work the VALUE magic on it.

A very bothersome solution would be to add all the values together like so:

```
=SUM(VALUE(RIGHT(A1, SEARCH(",",A1))),VALUE(RIGHT(A2, SEARCH(",",A2))))
```

But that does not seem optimal. I tried around with IF but it seems that what I am missing is simply the While/For loop to iterate through a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **A1** through **A10**, pick a cell and enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A10,",",CHAR(1),2),FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1:A10,",",CHAR(1),2))+1,9999))))
```

The formula isolates the string after the **second** comma; converts it into an integer; and then sums the integers.

[image]

*(just be sure that your `SUMPRODUCT()` covers only cells with data and not any blank cells)*

**EDIT#1:**

a somewhat shorter formula is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A10,",",REPT(" ",LEN(A1:A10))),LEN(A1:A10))))
```

**EDIT#2:**

The "shorter" formula works by replacing all commas with a great number of spaces, so many spaces in fact, that when we look at the `RIGHT()` part of the expanded string, all we see are spaces followed by some numbers.  `TRIM()` removes these spaces, leaving us the numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm :D Would you mind explaining how the shorter formula works?

Comment: @ZuJiry  See my **EDIT#2**

Comment: So we get the numbers then the SUMPRODUCT adds them up. Very cool! Thanks again ;)